# Tip of the day: don't use the [hints-and-tips] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [hints-and-tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hints-and-tips) tag currently has no tag wiki and only 5 questions, all but one of which are close-worthy.

This is a rather blatant Meta tag.

Here's the thing: two of the off-topic ones have historical locks, so obviously the community can't edit the tag out. Unfortunately, there is no link to flag for moderator intervention.

Can this tag be burninated? This isn't much work at all, except that moderators need to remove the tag from those two questions.

Comment: God, I really hope no one went in and *just* removed the tags...there's one or two questions which look like they could be edited into shape.

Comment: @Makoto I haven't edited any of them, it seemed better to see what Meta said first in this case (especially since I *can't* edit the locked questions without moderator assistance).

Comment: Related meta tag: [tag:tips-and-tricks], 11 questions, 1 overlapping, mostly closed but some with historical locks. Edit: apparently all historically locked, but we should still remove it. I can't do anything with those locked questions though

Comment: @Makoto Well looks like it now just has 3 questions, 2 of them are closed and 2 of them are locked.

Comment: @JoeW: Yeah.  We went in and deleted one, and I edited one that wasn't off-topic and removed its tag.  We didn't *just* remove the tags in those cases.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, I was going to ask if someone deleted the most recent one - I only have 5k reputation and can't see deleted posts yet. The most recent question was garbage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I went through and removed [hints-and-tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hints-and-tips) from all the locked questions. The remainder can be reviewed by the community.

I saw the same thing Erik did, so I also removed [tips-and-tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) from locked questions.